# objects disappear on angular template recompilation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z9XK3/6/

```
<div ng-app="miniapp">
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
        <span ng-bind-html-unsafe="variable"></span>       
        <span ng-bind-html-unsafe="variableB"></span>      
        <span class="clone">Clone me Clone me</span>
    </div>    
</div>

<div class="destination"></div>

var $scope;
var app = angular.module('miniapp', []);

function Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.variable = $('<span>100</span>');
    $scope.variableB = 'String';
}

app.directive('clone', ['$compile', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('click', function(){
              var newTemplate = '<span ng-bind-html-unsafe="variable"></span><span ng-bind-html-unsafe="variableB"></span> ';
              var compiledOutput = $compile(newTemplate)(scope);
              scope.$apply();
              compiledOutput.prependTo($('.destination'));
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Try clicking on the "Clone me Clone me link"

Notice that in the original template, the `<span>100</span>` disappears since it is an object whereas the 'String' string would still appear.

Why is this happening? And moreover, how can I prevent this such that once I click the "Clone me Clone me" link, the original `<span>100</span>` will not disappear?

(Note: this is a simplification of a real problem that I'm facing. In this case I can solve this by wrapping `<div ng-controller="Ctrl"></div>` around the newTemplate variable. However in the real problem I'm facing adding the ng-controller div will not solve the problem so please provide me with some new insights)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why it's happening, but why exactly do you have `<span>100</span>` wrapped with `$();`? "100" remains after clicking "Clone me Clone me" if you remove `$();`, so if that isn't necessary code your problem is solved.

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.variable = '<span>100</span>';
    $scope.variableB = 'String';
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z9XK3/8/